# How to do the summation in the linux shell

Tags: linux, bash

I know how to do the summation in one line ,I can use awk.But if the situation is something different,What should I do? For example,

```
orange     2000
orange     1000
orange     1500
apple      900
apple      1100
peach      1500
peach      800
peach      1200
```

And I want to get the total of each fruit respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` for that as well, by using an associative array:

```
pax> echo 'orange 2000
orange 1000
orange 1500
apple 900
apple 1100
peach 1500
peach 800
peach 1200' | awk 'NF>=2{sum[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in sum){print i" "sum[i]}}'

orange 4500
apple 2000
peach 3500
```

---

Looking at the script in detail:

```
NF >= 2 {                   # Want at least two fields
    sum[$1] += $2           # For each line, add to sum for that key
}
END {                       # After all lines processed.
    for (i in sum) {        # Process each key in sum array
        print i" "sum[i]    # Output key and sum
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your command in shell ,and succeed to get my goal. I need some time to understand the associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using switch case in bash. This would work even if the fruits are not in order.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=fruits.txt

while read -r line
do
        fruit=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }'`

        case "$fruit" in
                orange )
                value=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`
                val_or=`expr $val_or + $value`
                ;;

                apple )
                value=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`
                val_ap=`expr $val_ap + $value`
                ;;

                peach )
                value=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`
                val_pe=`expr $val_pe + $value`
                ;;
        esac
done < $file
        echo "orange: $val_or\napple: $val_ap\npeach: $val_pe\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

*GNU* [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
datamash -W -g1 sum 2 < fruit
```

Output:

```
orange  4500
apple   2000
peach   3500
```